# regex to replace all leading ">" with only one ">"

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I make an expression to match and replace all leading `>` with only one `>`

I tried using `^>(.*?)[^\W]+` but that doesn't seem to be working for all cases.

**Some of the possible cases:**

```
>> >> > some matching <string> goes in here >...
>   > >
>   > >\n
>
```

**Should look like**

```
> some matching <string> goes in here >...
>
>
>
```

Comment: You mean all leading `>` up to the first non-whitespace character that isn't a `>`? Do you also want to replace leading spaces with a single space (e.g., should `">>_>____text"` become `">_text"` or `">____text"` --where `_` represents a space because SO comments don't preserve spaces)?

Comment: That's correct. `">>_>____text"` become `">_text"`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for

```
/^[>\t ]+/
```

to replace with `"> "`

Comment: your pattern can match only spaces or tab now

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Yeah, you can use `\s` as well to match all whitespaces, but then it will match across lines and I thought the OP doesn't want that… not sure though.

Comment: I haven't seen that there s a > on each line.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

```
/>[>\s]+/g
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kS9ny/

to only affect leading... add a `^` or remove the `g`

```
/^>[>\s]+/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kS9ny/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace(/^(\s*>\s*)+/gm, '> ');
```

Comment: the second `\s*` is not necessary

Comment: @Anirudh How do you know? He may want to remove trailing spaces after the last leading `>` and convert them to one space.

Comment: @feeela It replaces `'>>>>>'` with `'> '`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
str.replace(/^>[>\s]*/gm, '>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this pattern, it should do what you want:

```
/(>\s*)+/
```

Comment: no..this would also replace anywhere in the string..he wants to replace it at the beginning of string only

Comment: op wants to replace at the beginning of string only..you are missing `^`

Comment: @RobinVanPersi Yeah probably with the OP's text. What if the line is `> > >> Some text > asd`? If it works perfectly and you just tried it, provide a jsFiddle that proves it with several test cases

Comment: @smerny Yeah I guess nothing. For some reason, I guess I misread the regex. At the same time, an explanation and demo by the answerer would've been nice instead of just saying "it works"

Comment: @smerny I didn't realize they left out the `g` flag. So technically, it's replacing the first match of ">" (and whitespace). So if the string didn't **start with** ">" (and whitespace), it would match something in the middle of the string and possibly mess it up. Also, it doesn't fix the string if it starts with whitespace. For example, the string `_____> string` - where `_` is a space

Comment: @Ian, although those do not appear to be use cases presented by the OP, your point is still valid and enough reason not to use this regex.